# Is it possible to run an elasticsearch aggregation query in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to run the following aggregation query in Kibana:

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_host": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "host",
        "size": 20
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can run it in the dev tools console (what used to be called Sense), but I would like to run it in the Kibana proper. Having a hard time figuring it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just create a Chart from Visualize tab.

Then buckets => X Axis (or Split Rows or whatever based on your chart type) => Terms => Choose your field.

[image]

Then click Advanced link and write {"size":10} to there:

[image]

Hope that helps!